# visual studio multiple forms closing and reopen

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, udp

hi i'm really new to UI applications and i'm trying to make a simple udp reader but everytime i close the program i have an error
stripped down code ..

```cs
namespace UDP_TEST_2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        double x;
        UdpClient Client = new UdpClient(5000);

        void recv(IAsyncResult res)
        {
            IPEndPoint RemoteIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5000);
            byte[] received = Client.EndReceive(res, ref RemoteIP);
            data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(received);
            Client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(recv), null);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
            timer1.Interval = 001;
            try
            {
                Client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(recv), null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text += ex.Message.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //reading all bytes ETC
        }
    }
}
```

the code works when its a single form but ever since i created a second form and call this one with f.showdialog();
first time it opes great but when i close it and reopen it with the button i get this error
code of the form that opens the read part

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 f = new Form1();
    f.ShowDialog();
}
```

error
[Error printed when i exit second screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeydA.png)

Comment: Start from: `using (var f = new Form1()) f.ShowDialog();` -- Assuming the Timer is the Timer Component or you have specified an `IContainer` object in its constructor, if you have declared the timer in code yourself.

Comment: Not sure what the Timer is for, though. You're using the asynchronous methods of UdpClient (or halfway there). -- [See a sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient.beginreceive?) that explains how to use those methods effectively. -- You can rise your own event when some data is received. Or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Close and Dispose the `UdpClient`. To do this you must override the form's `Dispose` method:

```cs
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing) {
        if (components != null) {
            components.Dispose();
        }

        if (Client != null) {
            Client.Close();
            Client = null;
        }
    }

    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

According to [UdpClient.Close Method / Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient.close?view=net-6.0#remarks):

> The Close disables the underlying Socket and releases all managed and unmanaged resources associated with the UdpClient.

Comment: `Dispose()` is overridden *by design* (it's in the `Designer.cs` file, though you can move it to the main class). The *problem* here is `ShowDialog()`: `Dispose()` is not called when a modal Form is shown, unless you declared it with a `using` statement (or, it *may* be called, but when it's too late). -- The OP can use the `FormClosing` or `FormClosed` event as an alternative way.

Comment: The same applies to the Timer, which will keep on running and ticking.